# My code works in xampp but not on the 000webhost.com

Tags: javascript, php, json

when i test it on localhost it works fine but when i use it on website "000webhost.com" console writes "BAD!" (as it is in code). I have no idea about why it is working on localhost and why not on 000webhost.com

There is my ajax:

```
var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var respText = xmlhttp.responseText;
    try{
      var json = JSON.parse(respText);
      console.log("GOOD!");
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log("BAD!");
    }
  }
}

xmlhttp.open(method,url + "?" + parameters,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

There is my php:

```
//$content is html code ex: <span>I'm here</span>
$resp = array(
  'r' => true,
  'response'  =>  $content,
);
echo json_encode($resp);
```

---

When i delete `try` it makes error `unexpected token <`

---

Sorry for my English and thank you for helping.

Comment: Log the exception `e`: `console.log(e);`

Comment: SyntaxError
message : "Unexpected token <"

Comment: Sounds like your JSON is invalid. Have you tried to [validate your JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: OMG :) I have tried `console.log(respText);` and there was 000webhost.com ad. I think i need `die` in php. **ty**

Comment: I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [checked your JSON](http://jsonlint.com/)? By the sounds of the error, it sounds like your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

sure to pass though the URL in the OPEN method, that is the only thing in your code